# Ring Oscillator on FPGA for TRNG

Tags: fpga, verilog, oscillator, xilinx, random-number

I am implementing a TRNG on an FPGA. This TRNG is based on jitter created by ring oscillator and I would like to know how to implement the given ring oscillator on FPGA so that jitter is generated.

```
module rng(start, r_out);
input start /* synthesis keep */;
reg rout /* synthesis keep */;
output r_out;
wire n0 /* synthesis keep */;
wire n1 /* synthesis keep */;
wire n2 /* synthesis keep */;
wire n3 /* synthesis keep */;
wire n4 /* synthesis keep */;
wire n5 /* synthesis keep */;
wire n6 /* synthesis keep */;
and a(n6,r0,start);
mynot x1(n6,n0);
mynot x2(n0,n1);
mynot x3(n1,n2);
mynot x4(n2,n3);
mynot x5(n3,n4);
mynot x6(n4,n5);
mynot x7(n5,r_out);
endmodule

module mynot(
    input x,
    output wire y
    );
    not(y,x);
endmodule
```

This is my code for ring oscillator.

```
module rng_tb;
reg start;
wire q;
rng uut(start,q);
initial
begin
start=0;
#50 start=1;
end
endmodule
```

This is the code for testbench.
[image]

The output now is don't care.

Comment: Have you tried to implement few of the oscillators and there was no jitter?

Comment: I have tried it and there is no output on simulation. The output is Z or it is in high impedance state.

Comment: Well, I would not expect to get any jitter on simulation as it is deterministic. You might want to add your code and the simulation results to the question.

Comment: I would not expect for this implementation to yield Z but rather "X" - unknown state, as you don't have initial values for the values for your simulation to consider.

Comment: Beware that it is very, very difficult to build that type of structure with an FPGA. 
Even using KEEP-this and KEEP-that, the tool tends to optimize out almost all of your gates. Check the post-implementation result of what really, really has been left of your gates at the end!!  And NO,  it will not give you TRNG. If it was that easy to make a TRNG, more people would be using it. e.g. your ring oscillators will be influenced by the power noise generated from your system clock and each other.

Comment: I know that this will not be a TRNG. What I am trying to do is to first create a ring oscillator.

Comment: I have attached the output too.

Comment: The port order in `mynot` is wrong. You define it as input,output but instantiate the connection order as output,input. Hense `r_out` has not source.  I'm surprised it compiled as `(r_out&start)` is an illegal output assignment. FYI, even with the fixing the port order it still might not oscillate due to compiler optimization.

Comment: Sorry for that blunder. I have updated the code and output. Can you check this now please?

Comment: Your simulation will never show the output of a ring oscillator. A ring oscillator relies on finite delays between the logic elements which are not taken into account during RTL Simulation (which is what you appear to be doing).

Comment: Thanks for the response. That's what I concluded from my simulation and this code works perfectly on FPGA.

Comment: BTW, X in simulation doesn't stand for don't care. It means that the output signal q is being driven by multiple sources which can't be resolved by the simulator.

Comment: I am not sure about that. But I wrote a new test bench in which at first I kept start 0 then after 50 ns I changed it to 1. This made my simulation stuck at 50ns and at that time the output keeps oscillating.

Comment: Maybe you are right about the X. I am more au fait with VHDL than Verilog and might have made an assumption about how you simulator works. Hey ho. But as you say, it works on the FPGA so why are you worried?

Comment: I asked this question when I made that stupid mistake and then didn't took down the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a ring oscillator, because r0 is unknown. You probably meant r_out:

```
and a(n6,r_out,start);
```

Also see: rout vs r_out.

If you correct your topology, you will run into another problem: a timing (delta) loop, basically a correct ring oscillator without delays will hang your simulator at 0 time. You will have to introduce a delay in your "mynot" macro to allow for exiting the delta steps from time 0.